# How to test conectivity between two aws sam local containers?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk, docker-network, aws-sam-cli

I have two lambdas in my local machine, lambdaA and lambdaB, what I want to do is invoke lambdaB from lambdaA by using the AWS SDK for Node.

So, in lambdaA I have this code.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const lambda = new AWS.Lambda({
    apiVersion: '2015-03-31',
    endpoint: 'http://172.17.0.1:3001', // docker0 network adapter ip
    sslEnabled: false,
    region: 'us-east-1',
    accessKeyId: 'any',
    secretAccessKey: 'any'
});

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    
    const response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        lambda.invoke({
            FunctionName: "LambdaB"
        })
        .promise()
        .then(data => {resolve(data)})
        .catch(e => {
            console.error(JSON.stringify(e))
            reject(e);
        });
    }); 
    console.log(response);

    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: "hello world from lambdaA"
    };
}
```

in lambdaB I have this code

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    callback(null, {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: "hello world from lambdaB"
    });
}
```

and I have this script to run my two lambdas locally.

```
sam local start-api -t ../lambdaA.yaml --warm-containers eager 2>&1 | sed -e 's/^/[LAMBDA_A] /' \
& sam local start-lambda -t ../lambdaB.yaml --warm-containers eager --host 172.17.0.1 --container-host-interface 0.0.0.0 2>&1 | sed -e 's/^/[LAMBDA_B] /'
```

Once my two lambdas are running I invoke lambdaA with `curl http://127.0.0.1:3001/test` and this lambdas tries to connect with lambdaB, but the problem is that I'm unable to connect with lambdaB, so I get a 502 code from my lambdaA because of a time out.

I followed the example from this repo:  https://github.com/jb3rndt/local-l2l-invocation and it works using an Ubuntu image and vagrant, but if I try the same example in my local environment it doesn't. That's why I think that maybe is something wrong with my docker network, my two lambdas are connecting in bridge network, I checked with `docker network inspect bridge` and I see my sam containers there.

Do you know how to test conectivity between two aws sam local containers ?

Or any idea in what's wrong with my environment ?

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, the same in the example I mentioned. And the vagrant solutions doesn't appear to be a solution, It's too slow n.n)'

Sorry for the long context, and thanks in advance :D